# Custom iterable objects

Tags: map, upvalues, built-in-symbols

I understand that to create objects with custom behavior with respect to existing code one uses upvalues. However, I'm at loss when it comes to guess what interface is expected from objects fed to built-in functions.

As a practical example, I would like to create a custom object `DiskList` that doesn't store its values in memory but dynamically reads them from a file. It is easy enough to write an upvalue for it so that the expression `mydisklist[[3]]` works as expected, but how do I make such object able to be passed to `Map`?

Comment: Why would you assume that `Map` uses iterators, in the first place? Help says it operates on the tree model of expressions, and makes a plenty of references to relevant concepts like levelspec and depth. So unless your "custom object" is a tree (and therefore nothing new to MMA), I would say `Map` is not the command for you.

Comment: @TheVee I'm not assuming that, it's the point of the question. What does `Map` expect from and object? Does it use `Length`, or does it use some compiled magic that I'll never be able to fool with an upvalue? and is there a way to "enumerate" these requirements rather than going by trial and error?

Comment: Well, Mathematica's only universal "interface" is a tree of objects. `Map` operates on this tree, and so do down/up/own/...value replacements. But the latter is an operation independent from the former. `Map` walks the actual structure (replacing (Map, f, (X, y, z)) by (X, (f, y), (f, z))), it does not *ask* for parts one-by-one. In fact, your object would not have parts, it just mimics being like that by transforming (Part, (DiskList, n)) (and presumably (Length, DiskList)) to something. But as pointed out above, you can write your own version of `Map` that would be based on `For` or `Table`.

Comment: Or, since `Map` would return the whole list anyway, you would be just as well of defining another set of upvalues that would first cache all the contents and then pass it on as a list. It would be natural to extend `Normal` for this purpose.

Answer (score 2):

Let's say that `DiskList` is just a symbolic wrapper that can trigger the reading of a file, with the semantic that words are the "atomic" elements. We might consider two different semantics for how `Part` and `Map` might work.

*For demonstration purposes, let's say we have the text of the U.S. constitution, `ExampleData[{"Text", "USConstitution"}]`, stored in a file with path `pathToFile`.*

### compute the structure that Map/Part can operate on natively

```
DiskList /: Part[DiskList[file_File], index_Integer] := Part[ReadList[file, Word], index];
DiskList /: Map[f_, DiskList[file_File]] := Map[f, ReadList[file, Word]];

DiskList[File[pathToFile]][[5]]
(* "of" *)

DiskList[File[pathToFile]][[10000]]
(* warning that part 10000 doesn't exist *)

StringLength /@ DiskList[File[pathToFile]] // Short
(* {8, 2, 3, 6, 2, 3, 6, 7, 2, 5, 2, 4, 1, 4, 7, 6, 9, 8, 6, <<8044>>, 3, 3, 8, 2, 3, 8, 3, 16, 5, 4, 7, 5, 2, 8, 2, 15, 5, 4, 11} *)

StringJoin[#, "TAG"] & /@ DiskList[File[pathToFile]] // Short
(* {"PREAMBLETAG", "WeTAG", "theTAG", <<8076>>, "shallTAG", "haveTAG", "intervened.TAG"} *)
```

One nice thing about this strategy is that we get all of the enhanced behaviors for free:

```
DiskList /: Part[DiskList[file_File], args___] := Part[ReadList[file, Word], args]
DiskList /: Map[f_, DiskList[file_File], args___] := Map[f, ReadList[file, Word], args];
```

This allows us to do stuff like this:

```
DiskList[File[pathToFile]][[5 ;; 7]]
(* {"of", "the", "United"} *)

DiskList[File[pathToFile]][[10000]]
(* EndOfFile *)
```

### force the iterative semantics

```
DiskList /: Part[DiskList[file_File], index_Integer] :=
  Module[
    {stream = OpenRead[file], value},
    Skip[stream, Word, index - 1];
    value = Read[stream, Word];
    Close[stream];
    value];
DiskList /: Map[f_, DiskList[file_File]] :=
  Module[
    {stream = OpenRead[file], value = {}, next},
    next = Read[stream, Word];
    While[
      EndOfFile =!= next,
      AppendTo[value, f[next]];
      next = Read[stream, Word]];
   Close[stream];
   value];
```

The advantage here is the ability to short circuit. This might be useful for `Part`, but not particularly for `Map`.

This strategy might be more useful for `Scan` if our goal is to perform some operation on each value read from the file rather than produce an output.

We have the immediate problem, however, of how to support the full behavior that `Part`/`Map`/`Scan` normally support. How should we handle level specs in `Map`? Do we want to build out our own support for `Span`?

### comments

Regarding

> what interface is expected from objects fed to built-in functions

this is one of those situations where different languages operate under different computational semantics, and it's generally unsafe (or just tedious and unnecessary) to try to impose one language's semantics on another. Mathematica has no notions of *interface* and *object* in the sense that OO languages do. As was pointed out in the comments, to Mathematica, everything is an expression, and expressions are almost synonymous to syntax trees.

Specifically, `Map` is not a generic (as in parameterized types) operator that defers certain responsibilities to the types/objects passed to it. `Map` simply implements computational behaviors on the expressions passed to it. So you can't "hook" into it by providing overriding behaviors in your custom "object classes".

Since the rules in `UpValues` are applied before those in `DownValues`, you can think of up values as interrupting the "typical" sequence of evaluation. You're simply telling the evaluation engine to consult the rules for a symbol in the body of the expression before consulting those of the head of the expression. That's it. You're not injecting a bundle of special, overriding implementations (an object) into a function template.